# c++ OpenGL display problem for gluLookAt

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I have been trying to solve this program:

> Program to draw a color cube and allow the user to move the camera suitably to experiment with perspective viewing. Also the cube should rotate.

I have completed the coding and here it is. It seems to work fine except for 1 simple problem:

```
//Program to draw a color cube and allow the user to move the camera suitably to experiment with perspective viewing
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut.h>

float v[][3] = {{-1,-1,1},{1,-1,1},{1,1,1},{-1,1,1},{-1,1,-1},{1,1,-1},{1,-1,-1},{-1,-1,-1}};
void drawPolygon(float a[3],float b[3],float c[3],float d[3])
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3fv(a);
        glVertex3fv(b);
        glVertex3fv(c);
        glVertex3fv(d);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
void drawCube(float v[8][3])
{
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[1],v[6],v[7]);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    drawPolygon(v[7],v[6],v[5],v[4]);
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    drawPolygon(v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5]);
    glColor3f(0,1,1);
    drawPolygon(v[1],v[2],v[5],v[6]);
    glColor3f(1,0,1);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[3],v[4],v[7]);

    glFlush();
}
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    //glRotatef(60,1,1,0);
    drawCube(v);
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int width,int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2,2,-2,2,-2,2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int btn,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        glRotatef(2,1,0,0);
    if(btn == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        glRotatef(2,0,1,0);
    if(btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        glRotatef(2,0,0,1);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
float ex=0,ey=0,ez=-10,cx=0,cy=0,cz=0,ux=0,uy=1,uz=0;
void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    if(key == 'x')
        ex += 0.1;
    if(key == 'X')
        ex -= 0.1;
    if(key == 'y')
        ey += 0.1;
    if(key == 'Y')
        ey -= 0.1;
    if(key == 'z')
        ez += 0.1;
    if(key == 'Z')
        ez -= 0.1;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluLookAt(ex,ey,ez,cx,cy,cz,ux,uy,uz);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutCreateWindow("spin cube");

    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The cube rotates by mouse clicks

The camera moves by x/X y/Y z/Z

But the problem is that when i first press a key the display vanishes. Then the 2nd time it comes with properly moved camera. Why? I want the camera to just move and not vanish the display. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your program:

- You're treating OpenGL like a scene graph with persistency – however OpenGL just draws pictures.
- You apply viewpoint transformation to the projection matrix.

Both is fundamentally wrong. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
//Program to draw a color cube and allow the user to move the camera suitably to experiment with perspective viewing
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut.h>

float v[][3] = {{-1,-1,1},{1,-1,1},{1,1,1},{-1,1,1},{-1,1,-1},{1,1,-1},{1,-1,-1},{-1,-1,-1}};
void drawPolygon(float a[3],float b[3],float c[3],float d[3])
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3fv(a);
        glVertex3fv(b);
        glVertex3fv(c);
        glVertex3fv(d);
    glEnd();
}

void drawCube(float v[8][3])
{
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[1],v[6],v[7]);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    drawPolygon(v[7],v[6],v[5],v[4]);
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    drawPolygon(v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5]);
    glColor3f(0,1,1);
    drawPolygon(v[1],v[2],v[5],v[6]);
    glColor3f(1,0,1);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[3],v[4],v[7]);
}

float ex=0,ey=0,ez=-10,cx=0,cy=0,cz=0,ux=0,uy=1,uz=0;
void display()
{
    int win_width, win_height;
    win_width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2,2,-2,2,-2,2);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(ex,ey,ez,cx,cy,cz,ux,uy,uz);

    glRotatef(rot_x,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(rot_y,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(rot_z,0,0,1);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    //glRotatef(60,1,1,0);
    drawCube(v);

    glFinish();
}

void mouse(int btn,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        rot_x += 2;

    if(btn == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
       rot_y += 2;

    if(btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
       rot_z += 2;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    if(key == 'x')
        ex += 0.1;
    if(key == 'X')
        ex -= 0.1;
    if(key == 'y')
        ey += 0.1;
    if(key == 'Y')
        ey -= 0.1;
    if(key == 'z')
        ez += 0.1;
    if(key == 'Z')
        ez -= 0.1;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutCreateWindow("spin cube");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`gluLookAt` shouldn't go in to the projection matrix but into the modelview. I would also suggest that you keep track of your cube rotation and eye position and apply them inside the display function instead:

```
//Program to draw a color cube and allow the user to move the camera suitably to experiment with perspective viewing
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut.h>

float ex=0,ey=0,ez=-10,cx=0,cy=0,cz=0,ux=0,uy=1,uz=0;
float cubex=0,cubey=0,cubez=0;
float v[][3] = {{-1,-1,1},{1,-1,1},{1,1,1},{-1,1,1},{-1,1,-1},{1,1,-1},{1,-1,-1},{-1,-1,-1}};
void drawPolygon(float a[3],float b[3],float c[3],float d[3])
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3fv(a);
        glVertex3fv(b);
        glVertex3fv(c);
        glVertex3fv(d);
    glEnd();
}
void drawCube(float v[8][3])
{
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[1],v[6],v[7]);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    drawPolygon(v[7],v[6],v[5],v[4]);
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    drawPolygon(v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5]);
    glColor3f(0,1,1);
    drawPolygon(v[1],v[2],v[5],v[6]);
    glColor3f(1,0,1);
    drawPolygon(v[0],v[3],v[4],v[7]);
}
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(ex,ey,ez,cx,cy,cz,ux,uy,uz);
    glRotatef(cubex, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(cubey, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(cubez, 0, 0, 1);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    //glRotatef(60,1,1,0);
    drawCube(v);
    glFinish();
}

void reshape(int width,int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2,2,-2,2,-2,2);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int btn,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        cubex += 2;
    if(btn == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        cubey += 2;
    if(btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        cubez += 2;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    if(key == 'x')
        ex += 0.1;
    if(key == 'X')
        ex -= 0.1;
    if(key == 'y')
        ey += 0.1;
    if(key == 'Y')
        ey -= 0.1;
    if(key == 'z')
        ez += 0.1;
    if(key == 'Z')
        ez -= 0.1;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutCreateWindow("spin cube");

    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

This isn't 100% equivalent to what you were originally trying to achieve since it applies three accumulated consecutive rotations around the x, y and z axis respectively instead of incremental ones.

Also you don't need all the `glFlush` calls, a single call to `glFinish` at the end of the rendering should be sufficient, or even better; swap to double buffered rendering and use `glutSwapBuffers` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) but why was that kind of rendering happening... any explanation would be helpful. I mean whats wrong in calling gluLookAt separate?

Comment: @footy: The projection matrix is kind of the "lens" of the OpenGL "camera" (OpenGL does not define a term "camera", it just moves around the whole world). Doing gluLookAt in the projection matrix is, as if you moved around the lens without the rest of the camera; doing this has it's applications (tilt/shift photography, you can do it in OpenGL, too by tilting/translating the projection matrix), but it's not usefull for setting the viewpoint.